# Python-Youtube-Api : Missing code parameter in response

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-api, authlib

I am testing the [python-youtube](https://pypi.org/project/python-youtube/) package, using the following code:

```py
from pyyoutube import Api

api = Api(
    client_id="yes-my-client-id-here-i-know",
    client_secret="yes-my-client-secret-here-i-know")

authorization_url = api.get_authorization_url()
access_token = api.generate_access_token(authorization_response=authorization_url[0])

print('authorization_url : >>>>>> ', authorization_url)
print('access_token      : >>>>>> ', access_token)
```

I get the following error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    access_token = api.generate_access_token(authorization_response=authorization_url[0])
  File "/Users/sleento/production/python-youtube-api/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyyoutube/api.py", line 263, in generate_access_token
    token = oauth_session.fetch_token(
  File "/Users/sleento/production/python-youtube-api/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 244, in fetch_token
    self._client.parse_request_uri_response(
  File "/Users/sleento/production/python-youtube-api/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/web_application.py", line 220, in parse_request_uri_response
    response = parse_authorization_code_response(uri, state=state)
  File "/Users/sleento/production/python-youtube-api/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 284, in parse_authorization_code_response
    raise MissingCodeError("Missing code parameter in response.")
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MissingCodeError: (missing_code) Missing code parameter in response.
```

Comment: Not familiar with this python-api, but, have you checked in [GitHub](https://github.com/sns-sdks/python-youtube/issues)?

Comment: Hi @Marco, i solve that, i was using ```client_id``` instead of  ```api_key``` parametrr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve that, I was using `client_id` instead of `api_key` parameter.

```py
from pyyoutube import Api

api = Api(
     api_key="yes-my-APi-key-here-i-know")

authorization_url = api.get_authorization_url()
print('authorization_url : >>>>>> ', authorization_url)
```